# Check for stability and asymptotic stability of the zero solution for a system

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, stability-in-odes

I am trying to show that the zero solution for a system is unstable even though both eigenvalues are negative.
This is the system:
$$ \vec{y'} = \begin{pmatrix}
-1 & e^{2t} \\
0 & -1
\end{pmatrix} \vec{y}.$$
I know that I have to find the fundamental matrix, but I am stuck.
This is what I have:
$$|A-\lambda I| = \begin{vmatrix}
-1- \lambda & e^{2t} \\
0 & -1-\lambda 
\end{vmatrix} = (-1-\lambda)^2,$$ which means that both eigenvalues are equal to -1.
The only eigenvector is: $\begin{bmatrix}
1  \\
0 
\end{bmatrix}$. Is this the fundamental matrix:
$$\begin{pmatrix} e^{-t} & e^{-t} \\ 0 &0
\end{pmatrix}$$
Do the zeros in the second imply that the zero solution is unstable, because there would be infinitely many solutions?
I want to know if I am at least on the right track; I would really appreciate the help.

Comment: There is only one eigenvector because $A$ is not diagonalizable. Your fundamental matrix is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Your system is unusual in that the coefficients of the matrix $A$ in the equation $y' = Ay$ are not constant.

I think it is best to solve this "from scratch" as a system of equations. In terms of the separate components of $\vec y$, the system is
$$
\frac{dy_1}{dt} = -y_1 + e^{2t}y_2\\
\frac{dy_2}{dt} = -y_2.
$$
Solving the second equation yields $y_2 = C_1 e^{-t}$. Plugging this solution into the first system gives us
$$
\frac{dy_1}{dt} = -y_1 + C_1 e^t \implies\\
\frac{dy_1}{dt} + y_1 = C_1 e^t \implies\\
e^t\frac{dy_1}{dt} + e^ty_1 = C_1 e^{2t} \implies\\
\frac d{dt}[e^t y_1] = C_1 e^{2t} \implies\\
e^t y_1 = \frac {C_1}{2} e^{2t} + C_2 \implies\\
y_1 = \frac{C_1}{2} e^t + C_2 e^{-t}.
$$
In other words, every solution to this differential equation can be written in the form
$$
\vec y = \pmatrix{e^{-t} & \frac 12 e^t \\0 & e^{-t}}\pmatrix{C_2\\C_1}.
$$

Comment: I'm sorry, I am still a bit confused, does this show that the zero solution is unstable?

Comment: It does. We see that even if the initial condition $\vec y(0) = (y_1(0),y_2(0))$ is "close to zero" (i.e. $\|\vec y(0)\|$ is small), $\vec y(t)$ fails to converge to $0$ except in the case that $y_2(0) = 0$.

Comment: @Lewis Alternatively, a solution is asymptotically stable iff its fundamental matrix converges. The fundamental matrix $\pmatrix{e^{-t} & \frac 12 e^t \\0 & e^{-t}}$ does not converge to zero, so the solution is not asymptotically stable